# Unexpected "authenticity of host can't be established."

Tags: ssh

Few months ago, I logged to server1 and scp files to server2. Now I want to do the same, but after the scp command I get message:

```
The authenticity of host ... can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
```

This is unexpected as I did this connection before. Unfortunately I already hit enter.

```
Warning: Permanently added ... (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Please, how can I list RSA key fingerprint of server2 so that i could know if they match? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just `ssh-keyscan typehostname`